# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') while navigating to another screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

While i am clicking on Get OTP button it shows me error that: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

I have tried many examples and solutions in stack overflow but didnt got solution yet

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';  
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, StatusBar, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';  
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';  
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';  
import BuyerLoginForm from './component/BuyerLoginForm';
import VendorLoginForm from './component/VendorLoginForm';


class BuyerHome extends React.Component {  
  render() {  
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return ( 
        <View style={styles.BuyerContainer}>  
        <ImageBackground source={require('./logo/backround.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent barStyle="dark-content" />
            <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./logo/applogo.png')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.title}><Text>Hey Buyer, please login via your number.</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <BuyerLoginForm navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>  
    );  
  }  
}  

class VendorHome extends React.Component {  
  render() {  
    return (  
      <View style={styles.VendorContainer}>  
        <ImageBackground source={require('./logo/backround.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent barStyle="dark-content" />
          <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./logo/applogo.png')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.title}><Text>Hey Vendor, please login via your number.</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <VendorLoginForm />
            </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>  
    );  
  }  
}  

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(  
    { 
      Home:{  
        screen:BuyerHome,  
        navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Buyer',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Icon name="ios-basket" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          )  
        }  
      },  
      Profile: {  
        screen:VendorHome,  
        navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Vendor',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Icon name="md-cart" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          )  
        }  
      },
    },  
    {  
      initialRouteName: "Home"
    },  
);
```

> BuyerLoginForm.js

```
import React from 'react';  
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';  
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';  
import BuyerVerify from '../screens/BuyerVerify';

class BuyerLogin extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.outer}>
                <View style={styles.inner}>
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}> 
                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Enter your contact number"
                        placeholderTextColor="#939eaf"
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                     />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Verify')}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Get OTP
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(  
    {  
        Login: BuyerLogin,  
        Verify: BuyerVerify  
    },
);  
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);  

const BuyerLoginForm = () => [
    <BuyerLogin key="1" />,
    <AppContainer key="2" />
]
export default BuyerLoginForm;
```

> BuyerVerify.js

```
import React from 'react';  
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';  

export default class BuyerVerify extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.outer}>

                <View style={styles.inner}>

                    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}> 
                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Enter your contact number"
                        placeholderTextColor="#939eaf"
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                     />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Get OTP
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

                </View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to navigate from BuyerLoginForm to BuyerVerify screen. Please help me to find solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've made a bit of a mess with all the structure here. It would be best to always generate the expo tab example offered and build on it as it is setup correctly. I would recommend that you setup your classes and application as such.

> BuyerHome.js

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, StatusBar, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';  
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';  
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';  
import BuyerLoginForm from './component/BuyerLoginForm';

class BuyerHome extends React.Component {  
  render() {  
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return ( 
        <View style={styles.BuyerContainer}>  
        <ImageBackground source={require('./logo/backround.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent barStyle="dark-content" />
            <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./logo/applogo.png')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.title}><Text>Hey Buyer, please login via your number.</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <BuyerLoginForm navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>  
    );  
  }  
}
export default BuyerHome;
```

> VendorHome.js

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, StatusBar, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';  
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';  
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';  
import VendorLoginForm from './component/VendorLoginForm';

class VendorHome extends React.Component {  
  render() {  
    return (  
      <View style={styles.VendorContainer}>  
        <ImageBackground source={require('./logo/backround.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent barStyle="dark-content" />
          <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./logo/applogo.png')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.title}><Text>Hey Vendor, please login via your number.</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <VendorLoginForm />
            </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>  
    );  
  }  
}
export default VendorHome;
```

> BuyerLogin.js

```
import React from 'react';  
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';  
import BuyerVerify from '../screens/BuyerVerify';

class BuyerLogin extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.outer}>
                <View style={styles.inner}>
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}> 
                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Enter your contact number"
                        placeholderTextColor="#939eaf"
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                     />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Verify')}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Get OTP
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default BuyerLogin;
```

> BuyerVerify.js

```
import React from 'react';  
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';  

export default class BuyerVerify extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.outer}>

                <View style={styles.inner}>

                    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}> 
                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Enter your contact number"
                        placeholderTextColor="#939eaf"
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                     />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Get OTP
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

                </View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default BuyerVerify;
```

> MainTabNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';  
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, StatusBar, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';  
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';  
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'; 

import BuyerLoginForm from './component/BuyerLoginForm';
import VendorLoginForm from './component/VendorLoginForm';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: BuyerHome,
});

      HomeStack.navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Buyer',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Icon name="ios-basket" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          )  
        };  

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: VendorHome,
});

      ProfileStack.navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Vendor',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Icon name="md-cart" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          )  
        };  
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    {   
      HomeStack,
      ProfileStack
    },    
);
```

> AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';
import BuyerLogin from './components/BuyerLogin';
import BuyerVerify from './components/BuyerVerify';

// every class you would to be able to navigate to that is not part of your tab put here
export default createSwitchNavigator({
      Main: MainTabNavigator,
      Login: BuyerLogin,
      Verify: BuyerVerify

  },
  {
      initialRouteName: 'Main'
  },
);
```

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  render() {


    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

            {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
              <AppNavigator />
            </View>

          );
    }
  }

  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Font.loadAsync({
        // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
        ...Icon.Ionicons.font,
      }),
    ]);
  };

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
    console.warn(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  safeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
});
```

I have given you the standard way your app should be organised and now your navigation should work the tab and app classes are separated. You should make sure you put every classes with the correct path to it and maybe make sure the imports are correct for each one of them I probably missed one or two. Hope this helps and that you have a better understanding of the structure you should have in an expo application and how the navigation should work.